# How to Trigger a Job in GitLab CI After a Specific Job in a Downstream Pipeline is Complete?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab CI/CD pipeline configuration where I use a local downstream pipeline along with another job that is not part of this downstream pipeline. My downstream pipeline has a manual job (job4_manual) that I occasionally want to run, but it's blocking the execution of my final job (test-job) even if I don't run it.

Here's how the pipelines are structured:

```
trigger:
stage1    stage2   stage3
job1 ->    job2  -> [ job3, job4_manual ] 

.gitlab-ci

downstream-stage    testing-stage
downstream.      -> test-job
```

I would like to execute test-job as soon as job3 is completed, regardless of whether job4_manual is run or not. I have tried setting allow_failure: true for job4_manual, but it did not solve the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?